# Electric field's area

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

How much area an electric field surrounds? since we're just able to draw the electric lines of force we sometimes think that the field is though 3d but surrounds a finite area. But is it measurable or it is spread to infinity?

Comment: Spread to infinity, even though it's effects become negligible after a certain separation

Comment: You can confine an electric field in a Faraday cage, if you want to, then the volume is finite.

Answer (score 1):

You can confine an electric field in a Faraday cage, if you want to, then the volume is finite. – CuriousOne

Comment: at least he/she referenced the original article...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform she